# How to handle rouding of numbers in systems

Tags: decimal, software-design

We can take Java as a perspective. Suppose we have a system that has items with a price. The price will take several operations, let's say 15 operations. the items' price will be divided multiplied, summed, subtracted with decimals over and over. Know lets say that our system talks to another system. That other system also makes operations to itens prices. In the end the price values of the two systems have to match exactly(cents). We are hipothetically talking about accounting systems. The chance of the two match is very rare, according to my experience. How can we handle such situation. Is there a rule for rounding?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say always calculate with the raw numbers (i.e. a lot of decimals) and transfer that number as well. Only for the comparison round to a less precise, previously agreed upon degree of precision (which is still precise enough for the purpose). That way you have matching results while maintaining high enough precision.
A factor to consider is the rounding method in case one side may differ. There are three I know about:

- The one which is taught in school: 0.5 --> 1.0
- Towards zero: 1.5 --> 1.0 but -2.5 --> -2.0
- Towards even, also called "Banker's rounding": 1.5 --> 2.0 but 2.5 --> 2.0